How to use Forge remappings when the complete backend is in its own folder
I am making a project in Solidity using Foundry for backend and Typescript for frontend. I decided to put the complete backend part in a backend folder and frontend part in frontend folder. The problem now is that the foundry.toml remappings that I was using are now completely broken. It gives a red line under every import statement stating "cannot find file at path".
A rough structure of how my folder looks like.
backend/
   lib/
   out/
   script/
   src/
   test/
   foundry.toml
   remappings.txt
frontend/

.gitattribute
Readme.md
I have tried the following ways

Put foundry.toml and remappings in the root folder.
Changed foundry.toml remapping to eg
"@openzeppelin/contracts=backend/lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts"

from
"@openzeppelin/contracts=lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts"



Nothing works.
My remapping.txt file looks like this:
@chainlink-testing/=lib/foundry-chainlink-toolkit/lib/chainlink-testing-framework/contracts/ethereum/
@chainlink/=lib/foundry-chainlink-toolkit/lib/chainlink-brownie-contracts/contracts/src/
@chainlink/contracts/=backend/lib/chainlink-brownie-contracts/contracts/
@openzeppelin/=lib/foundry-chainlink-toolkit/lib/openzeppelin-contracts/
@openzeppelin/contracts/=backend/lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/
@openzeppelin/contracts/=lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/
@solmate/=backend/lib/solmate/src/
chainlink-brownie-contracts/=lib/chainlink-brownie-contracts/
chainlink-testing-framework/=lib/foundry-chainlink-toolkit/lib/chainlink-testing-framework/contracts/
ds-test/=lib/solmate/lib/ds-test/src/
erc4626-tests/=lib/openzeppelin-contracts/lib/erc4626-tests/
forge-std/=lib/forge-std/src/
foundry-chainlink-toolkit/=lib/foundry-chainlink-toolkit/
openzeppelin-contracts/=lib/openzeppelin-contracts/
solmate/=lib/solmate/src/

What I can do is not use the remappings and directly use the absolute path in my contracts. I am new to solidity so any suggestion(s) is/are welcome.
